# avro deserialization after changing java package name

Tags: avro

I would like to change the java package names for our avro classes.
But after this change, how can I read my existing avro files?

For example, I have avro files created by serializing the avro class “com.abc.MyObject”.  And now I want to change the class to “com.xyz.MyObject”.

What is the best way to read avro files that were created with the old package name?  Is there a way to tell deserialization that the class name “com.abc.MyObject” found in the avro files is now “com.xyz.MyObject”?

My hope is that I can read the avro files containing the old package names, but write the object to our data store (HBase) with the new package names.

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 2):

I was mistakenly thinking the problem was larger than what it actually was.

When trying to read existing avro files after the package name change, I was getting this error:
org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found com.abc.PropertyValueType, expecting com.xyz.PropertyValueType

In my schema, the PropertyValueType enum was defined as an enum for this field:

```
{"name": "value_type", "type": {"type":"enum", "name":"PropertyValueType", "symbols" : ["VALUE_STRING", "VALUE_DOUBLE", "VALUE_DATE", "VALUE_LONG"]} }
```

The solution I discovered for the error above is aliases:
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Aliases

I updated the avro schema as follows:

```
{"name": "value_type", "type": {"type":"enum", "name":"PropertyValueType", "symbols" : ["VALUE_STRING", "VALUE_DOUBLE", "VALUE_DATE", "VALUE_LONG"], "aliases" : ["com.abc.PropertyValueType"]} }
```

And now my code has no issue reading the avro files created before my package name changes.